# What java do i have for my event listener

Tags: java, events

I have a Java class and although I know OO C# C++ but not handy with Java.
This class runs on the web and it is a page that has a few controls on it.
What I like to do is to create a listener so when F1 is pressed I could pop up a message for start or something.... I have been told that there are many flavours of Java and the listener that I write depends on what Java it is that I am using....
1- How do I figure out what flavour or Java I have so I could continue my research on how to do a Key-board even listener on this code.
Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using??  AWT/Swing/AWT/GWT/JSP ... something else I don't know about?  Oh, wait, are we talking about JavaScript!? *"1- How do I figure out what flavour or Java"* - How about you provide the code you've actually written to this point?!

Answer (score 1):

You can find your Java version by doing:

```
$java -version
```

in the terminal.

I suspect what you need to know is what GUI framework you're using. There are three GUI frameworks:

1. AWT
2. Swing
3. JavaFX

Unless your Java learning resource is very old, you are probably working with Swing or JavaFX- if you see words like **JFrame**, **JApplet**, or **JPanel**, you're using Swing. If you see **Stages** or **Groups**, you are working with JavaFX.

Here is more information related to Swing and JavaFX:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm

Comment: Using Control Panel the Java version is 1.8 . Could not find any JPanel and JApplet or JFrame so I am guessing it is JavaFX . This is actually a 4GL language that gets converted to Java and the compiled and used as a web page. If this stackover... had an attachment option , I could have attached the Java class for you  to confirm it is JavaFX.... Cheers